# Terminal Command Colors

Tags: command-line, terminal, colors, zsh, themes

I like to have a really beatiful console style.
I use zsh and I have changed my theme to "agnoster"
[image]
See it under: [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes)

My problem is that I do not have OS X and iTerm2 but I want to have these nice colors for the commands (like cd or ssh)

Here:(kde4 and /usr/bin/konsole)
[image]

ansi colors:
[image]

Can someone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the syntax highlighting like in the example (different colors for commands, underlined paths) you can use [zsh-syntax-highlighting](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting). 
It also supports being used as *oh-my-zsh* plugin and instructions on how to do so are in the *README.md*.

Answer (score 2):

You need the **Solarized Dark colorscheme**, as stated on the [*oh-my-zsh* theme site](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/themes):

> (Shown with Solarized Dark colorscheme and patched Menlo 14pt in iTerm 2)

You don't state which terminal emulator you use (only which you are *not* using), but assuming a standard X terminal you should succeed by downloading the latest [Solarized version](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized/files/solarized.zip) and appending the content of the contained file `solarized/xresources-colors-solarized/Xresources` to your `~/.Xresources` config file. Reload the X system.

But be aware, that this will change the colors globally, independent of the command.

Comment: thank you for your answer! I have already appended Xresources to my Xresources.desktop. I'm using kde4 and konsole (/usr/bin/konsole). but I do not get the style altought solarized dark is selected. see an additional pic above

Comment: @x4k3p: The blue looks like it is solarized. Can you please try this script, to show all ansi colors: http://www.linuxfocus.org/common/src2/article335/showansicol.tar.gz

Comment: @x4k3p: Looks fine... Perhaps you can rephrase your question, I don't get at the moment what colors you think are "wrong"...

Comment: I just wanted to have the commands (like cd, touch, ssh aso.) in different color or this in the pic. doesn't matter. maybe I will use fish